# React - Open route as a popup

Tags: reactjs, react-router, popup

I have a web application which builds with reactjs. In this application, I want to open a route inside a popup window. The process is like this;
There is a patient details page. inside that page, the user can see a details edit button. whenever the user clicks that button I want to open my editPatient route as a popup. What is the easy and best way to do this??
this is the route `<Route path={"/patient/:id"} component={EditPatient}/>`

Comment: why not a div based model to open the route?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you said

Comment: popup will be like external window, if you use div based model dialog, it will be part of your container only and you can achieve what you are looking for. Check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-modal

Comment: By pop up do you mean a modal?

Comment: Yes, as a modal @SakoBu